# Apidoc installed as global: how to run it?

Tags: bash, yarnpkg, api-doc

I've installed [APIDoc.js](http://apidocjs.com) packages *globally*, using `yarn`.

```
yarn global add apidoc
```

I'm on a Debian 9.8.

Actually...

```
which apidoc
```

... doesn't return any path. So running ...

```
apidoc
```

... results in a

```
command not found
```

How can I execute apidoc when globally installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended running it using `npx`

```
npx apidoc ...< rest of params >
```